# Return type of Linq on Datatable

Tags: vb.net, linq, uipath

I have a datatable with two columns ID & Role.
Same ID can have multiple roles.
I need to convert this table to a comma separated grouped table.
I am trying to use following query but unable to solve the issue.

**LINQ:**

```
From row As DataRow In dtData.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow)
Group row By id = row.Field(Of Integer)("ID") Into Group
Select ID, Role = String.Join(",", From i In Group Select i.Field(Of String)("Role"))
```

**Issue**
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Update 1:

Table structure

[image]

Needed table Structure

[image]

Comment: Your query will return a generic `IEnumerable` of whatever you specify in the `Select` clause. You're not selecting `DataRows` there so you're not going to produce an `IEnumerable(Of DataRow)`. I don't really see how you can select `DataRows` though, because you're trying to return items that contain data from multiple `DataRows`.

Comment: Thanks @ jmcilhinney I was checking DataTable.LoadDataRow which receives  object Array. Can I use that in the linq to populate another DataTable and set return type of linq as object.

Comment: Something like `From row As DataRow In dtData.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow) Group row By id = row.Field(Of Integer)("ID") Into Group Select dtNew.LoadDataRow(New Object[] { ID, Role = String.Join(",", From i In Group Select i.Field(Of String)("Role")) }, False)`

Answer (score 0):

I am kind of confused by what you are wanting as the ultimate outcome.  An idea that may guide you but not be exactly what you want is you can change a DataTable to an anonymous projection and then get what you want out of that.  You can do a 'Select' off a DataTable which enters into an extension method of 'what' do you want to select.  If I was to do a new {} without any class or container object after the 'new' I would be scoped to just a method or not.  This is a good advantage when you want to mold something for a specific use in just a single method to use tailored to a specific view.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        DataTable d = new DataTable();
        d.Columns.Add("ItemName", typeof(string));
        d.Columns.Add("MinValue", typeof(float));
        d.Columns.Add("MaxValue", typeof(float));

        d.Rows.Add("Widget1", 0.1, 0.2);
        d.Rows.Add("Widget2", 0.2, 0.4);
        d.Rows.Add("Widget3", 0.1, 0.2);

        var dataTable = d.AsEnumerable();

        //What do you want to select?  The new {} without an indicator means anonymous type projection.  This will exist only in 
        // the scope listed.
        var data = dataTable.Select(x => new { ItemName = x[0], MinValue = x[1], MaxValue = x[2] }).ToList();

        //My 'data' type is now well typed for it's properties in the scope it's in.
        var joined = String.Join(", ", data.Select(x => x.ItemName).ToList());

        Console.WriteLine(joined);
        Console.WriteLine($"{data.Count}");

        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**EDIT 1-26-18**
Strange I thought I updated the code yesterday.  To get a reusable object you could bind your front end to, you just make a POCO like so:

```
 public class Foo
 {
     public string Bar { get; set; }
     public string MinAndMax { get; set; }
 }
```

While you could make another DataTable, frankly DataTables are like WinForms.  They get the job done, but they are archaic and not friendly to do Linq with as easily as just a well formed POCO.  And if you get into using Linq it will play better with well formed objects and they are easy to create.

```
 var data = dataTable.Select(x => new Foo { Bar = x[0].ToString(), MinAndMax = $"{x[1]} {x[2]}" }).ToList();

 //My 'data' type is now well typed for 'Foo' class and it's properties in the scope it's in.
 var joined = String.Join(", ", data.Select(x => $"{x.Bar} {x.MinAndMax}").ToList());
```

Comment: thanks djangojazz I have updated the question and added the initial data table and expected resultant data table. UiPath does not recognize dynamic data types so I need to explicitly specify the return type of each statement.

Comment: You can add a specific class to act as POCO and go to assignment of that.  I don't know your data but essentially if you have to concatenate multiple fields you may do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a linq like in your comments just that this returns a list of arrays of string:

[image: result of linq]

Here is the code:

```
(From row As DataRow In myDatatable
Group row By id = row.Field(Of String)("ID") Into Group
Select {id, String.Join(",", From i In Group Select i.Field(Of String)("Role"))}).ToList
```

If you need the result in a datatable you can build a new datatable

[image: create newDatatable]

Make a for each of result and use the activity **Add data row**. In ArrayRow add the item and in DataTable the new data table

[image: Add data row properties]

If you use the activity **Output data table** you can see the results

[image: Output data table]